# Headless Media Player playing remote hosted mp4 files

Tags: media-player, raspberry-pi

I am trying to figure out best path for the following:

1. An inexpensive headless internet device that I can control remotely to stream media files (mostly mp4).
2. Play hosted mp4 based on schedule (time and day).
3. Movies would be hosted on a remote web server.
4. I would use or create script in PHP to upload movie to hosted folder.
5. Internet device would read script and play remote file per schedule.

I feel this can be done with a Raspberry Pi but need some direction. Goal would be to connect the hdmi output of Pi into a modulator and play the mp4 so it will show up on modulated channel 6 for example. I need to remotely upload the mp4 to the hosted server through a script or my script, schedule when file should play, play random files when no schedule is available, monitor status of device (maybe restart). Need something reliable as I will be off-site the majority of the time. Help would be appreciated. Not sure where to start.Solution does not need to include a pi. It just seemed logical. Not sure how long a pi can run without failure or reboot.